# Calculating the average days between records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Given that I have a `Foo` model w/ the standard Rails timestamp columns what would be the most efficient way to calculate the average number of days between records being created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `maximum` and `minimum` class methods of your model will use the SQL aggregate functions `min()` and `max()` to find the extreme values efficiently.

```
span_secs = Foo.maximum(:created_at) - Foo.minimum(:created_at)
avg_secs = span_secs / (Foo.count - 1)
avg_days = avg_secs / (24 * 60 * 60)
```

Comment: Not sure this calculates "the average number of days between records being created" (depends on how the OP defines it). Consider [1, 3, 7]. (7 - 1)/3 => 2. But ((3 - 1) + (7 - 3)) / 2 => 3

Comment: @AlistairIsrael: With your example, my code gives `(7 - 1) / (3 - 1) => 6 / 2 => 3`.

Comment: [0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6] - average 3,75
( 8 - 0 ) / (8 - 1) - 1.1428571428571428

Answer (score 0):

If you use MySQL

```
secs = Foo.where("created_at IS NOT NULL").average("UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at)").to_i
DateTime.strptime secs.to_s, "%s"
```