# Calculate average number of days between datetimes in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to take a list of datetimes in Ruby and then calculate the number of days **between** them and then average those dates. Is this correct? Is there a shorter way to do this?

```
dates = ["2012-08-05 00:00:00 UTC", "2012-06-17 00:00:00 UTC", "2012-06-15 00:00:00 UTC", "2011-06-06 00:00:00 UTC"]

difference = Array.new

dates.each_with_index do |date, index|
    if index != 0
        difference << date.to_date - dates[index - 1].to_date
    end
end

avg = difference.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / arr.size
```

And then would that output it in days format?

You can give me a Rails version as well if you'd like as I'll be pulling the datetimes from a model field.

Comment: Your question would be better if the array `dates` contained actual dates in a common format.  Probably three would be enough.  For example: `dates = ["Nov 21, 2013", "Dec 22, 2013", "Jan 20, 2014"]`  Then show the output you get for those date.  That would also allow readers to test code that they may wish to suggest.

Comment: Ok thanks. I added some datetimes.

Comment: You could also use Ruby's wonderful `Time.parse()` function!  It usually can figure out how to automagically convert a string into a `Time` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have an off-by-one problem. If you have `n` values in `dates` then you'll have `n-1` differences between consecutive pairs so your `avg` should be:

```
avg = difference.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / (arr.size - 1)
```

And your [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) is just a long winded way of saying `inject(:+)` so you could say:

```
avg = difference.inject(:+).to_f / (arr.size - 1)
```

In any case, you could use [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map) and [`each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) to make it a bit nicer:

```
dates.map(&:to_date).each_cons(2).map { |d1, d2| d1 - d2 }.inject(:+) / (dates.length - 1)
```

First we can convert everything to dates in one pass with `map(&:to_date)` rather than converting every time we need a date instead of a string. Then the `each_cons(2)` iterates over the array in consecutive pairs (i.e. `[1,2,3,4]` is iterated as `[[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]]`). Then a simple `map` to get the differences between the pairs and `inject(:+)` to add them all up.

The above will leave you with a [`Rational`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Rational.html) but you can `to_f` or `to_i` that if you need a floating point or integer value.

Comment: This is pure awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I might be off here, but i think this should work:

```
require 'date'
dates.map!{|x| Date.parse(x)}.sort!
p (dates.last - dates.first)/(dates.size - 1) #=> (142/1)
```

or is this more beautiful?

```
first, last = dates.map!{ |x| Date.parse(x) }.minmax
p (last - first)/(dates.size - 1) #=> (142/1)
```

Comment: Nice and clean, hiro.

Comment: As long as the dates don't switch direction at the end points; for example, `%w[2012-08-05 2012-06-17 2012-06-15 2011-06-06 2011-06-20]` would be problematic as the sign change in the last difference throws off the implicit cancelations in your min/max.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
def room_expiry_date_in_days(room)
 a=room.expiry_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
 b=room.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
 a=Date.parse(a)
 b=Date.parse(b)
 days=(a-b).to_i
 return  "#{pluralize(days, 'day',"days")} left"
end
```

or if I've understood incorrectly, then there's always:

```
span_secs = Foo.maximum(:created_at) - Foo.minimum(:created_at)
avg_secs = span_secs / (Foo.count - 1)
avg_days = avg_secs / (24 * 60 * 60)
```

See: [Calculating the average days between records in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016669/calculating-the-average-days-between-records-in-rails)

Comment: Does this calculate the number of days between each date and then average those? Maybe I'm missing something.